# Obtener documento mas reciente en Carpeta Local

Tags: javascript, nodejs, funciones

Mi objetivo es por medio de Nodejs, ubicarme en una carpeta local (Carpeta en mi pc, no base de datos-aclarando) y obtener la ruta del archivo mas reciente (Ultimo en ser actualizado o en ser añadido), puedo leer documentos utilizando readFile, pero no se como abarcar el caso que e propuesto.
Gracias de Antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenes que usar `fs.stat("filename")`

```javascript
const basedir = process.env.HOME;
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");

// primero leemos el directorio
const filenames = await fs.readdir(basedir);

for(const filename of filenames) {
  // y obtenemos el stat de cada archivo
  const stat = await fs.stat(path.join(basedir, filename))
  const mtime = stat.mtime; // modification time
}
```

Te recomiendo leer la documentación oficial sobre el módulo `fs` en nodejs.org